# Why is neovim on the Debian repository so old?

Tags: neovim, linux-debian

Latest neovim release is 0.9.5.
On [Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/neovim) it's [0.7.2-8](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/tag/v0.7.2)—Why?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

While adding links to your Question, I noticed that the release you mention is on the testing and unstable channels. A newer release is in experimental. Debian I believe generally emphasizes stability over rapid releases, so perhaps you simply misunderstood the Debian packaging process and ethos?

I’m not a Debian expert, but I’m sure there’s a way to install from the experimental channel if you want it.

Comment: I would not call myself a Debian expert either but I agree. I've joked that Debian's slogan should be "the best software from five years ago". I'd compile it myself if I wanted the latest (Neo)Vim version. Debian is popular and widely supported, there are detailed instructions how to do it.